# Would a multilevel model (random effects) suit better

Tags: mathematical-statistics, econometrics, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

I have a question about whether multilevel modeling is appropriate in my situation. I’m working on an analysis looking at the effect of an training camp for factory workers in 20 different factories with a quit rates of each factory. My data is an unbalanced panel, with outcome and independent variable varying by time.

Research questions: • what is effect of the Training camp on quit rates?

I was thinking of a fixed effects model but as an addition, was thinking of adding in employee (factory worker) level covariates none of which are time-varying.

Given the multiple levels in my model (factory level and employee level) would it be advisable to run a Multilevel model instead (random effects).

Any potential drawbacks with this approach?

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: How many time points do you have? You should definitely take into account that your observations are clustered within different factories, and a multilevel model does this well, and you can easily use "trait-like" (i.e. non-time-covarying) fixed predictors in a multilevel model. However - and this may be just my personal issue - I usually find it difficult to include a time variable into a regression model. It's definitely doable, just you need to consider carefully whether you want time to be a continuous predictor, a factorial predictor, or a random effect.